# Ensure 32-bit JVM in Install4J?

Tags: java, jvm, install4j

I'm using Install4J mostly for it's great jar file optimization and support for pack200. The main hiccup I'm running up against is that we have several native libraries that are 32-bit only. We need to run with a 32 bit JVM for those to work, ideally dynamically downloding one and installing it when one's not there.

The case that's tricky is when there is a JVM installed above the minimum version we need, but that's 64-bit instead of 32-bit. Any way we can detect that and download and install a 32-bit JVM to run with instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually had missed the fact that Install4J already handles this. Since the launcher itself is 32 bit, Install4J requires a 32 bit JVM. So it downloads one automatically if it's not there.

Answer (score 0):

You can bundle the 32bit JRE to installer. And instruct Install4J not to use already existing Java on user's machine but rather the one you have bundled.

I had similar problem, check [Running install4j on 64bit JRE in Win](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10896026/running-install4j-on-64bit-jre-in-win).